# Symfony and Eclipse: I can not go to the function or class using F3

Tags: eclipse, symfony1

I'm using Eclipse (Build id: 20090920-1017) to write my Symfony web application and in many cases I can not "go" to the declaration of functions or classes (you know placing the cursor where the class or the function is called and then pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>).

For example: I have this class:

```
class UsuarioFormFilter extends BaseUsuarioFormFilter{

}
```

When I try to go to `BaseUsuarioFormFilter` it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is configured like php project?

```
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: I just go to the folder that contains BaseUsuarioFormFilter and right click on it and then "Build Path">"Use as source folder".

Comment: Anyway, I have this: $this->usuario = $this->getRoute()->getObject(); I right clicked on the symfony folder (now it is named lib/vendor/
symfony), then "Build Path">"Use as source folder", then F3 but it doesn't go to the declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Nice =)
Also, i think you can use "lib" like source folder.